# PassportJS redirect not working when using AngularJS $http to POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, passport.js

I'm using passportJS for user authentication. This is in my app's routes, which authenticates login info.

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

The redirection works when I have my form like so:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```

But when I use Angular's `ng-submit` with a `$http.post('/login')` method, the redirect doesn't trigger. The login *does* work, but the redirect doesn't.

```
<form ng-submit="submitLogin(name,password)">
  ...
</form>
```

**MainController.js**

```
$scope.loginSubmit = function(n,p) {
    $http.post('/login', {
      email: n,
      password: p
    });
};
```

Why does Angular prevent the redirect from working?

Comment: Thanks for this! Ran into this problem too...we might need to submit a bug? It seems like from checking out my console that Angular decides to go and get the redirect page, and returns that as html...at least that's what it seems like to me. The problem is then the thing that is actually returned to angular is a 200 response, with a body that's just HTML.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure *why* the redirect doesn't work with Angular, but I figured out a way to solve my problem.

**We need to send stuff back to Angular, and then use $location.path() to handle the redirect.**

[PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/) suggests to use a custom callback if the simple authenticate functionality isn't enough.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        res.send({
          message: 'no user'
        });
      }
      req.login(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        res.send({
          message: 'logged in'
        });
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

Instead of using `res.redirect()`, we simply send a message back to Angular.

**Controller**

```
$http.post('/login', {
  email: n,
  password: p
})
.success(function(data) {
  if (data.message === 'logged in') {
    $location.path('/presents');
});
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out, i was facing the same problem now works like a charm :)